# compiling and running a c program using exec()

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, cc

I am writing a program using execv() that compiles and runs another program. I've written up a simple C program named helloWorld.c that when executed outputs, "Hello world," and a second file named testExec.c that is supposed to compile and run helloWorld.c. I've been looking around everywhere to find a way to do this, but I haven't found any answers. The code in testExec.c is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
   char *args[] = {"./hellWorld.c", "./a.out", NULL};
   execv("usr/bin/cc", args);
   return 0;
}
```

testExec.c compiles with no errors. However, when I run it I get an error that says, "fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found. compilation terminated." Which I think means helloWorld.c is being compiled but when it comes time to run helloWorld.c this error is thrown. I thought maybe that was because I had a.out and helloWorld.c prefaced with './'. I removed './' from both, then either one individually, and still no luck.

I also did 'sudo apt-get install build-essential' along with 'sudo apt-get install gcc'. I wasn't sure if that would resolve the issue but I really wasn't sure what else to try. Anyway, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `cc --help` says the output filename needs to be specified via the `-o` option, but you seem to be passing it without `-o`. That probably means it is treated as an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the leading slash when calling `cc`.

Also, the first argument in the argument list is the name of the executable.  The actual arguments come after that.  You're also not using `-o` to specify the name of the output file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
   char *args[] = {"cc", "-o", "./a.out", "./hellWorld.c", NULL};
   execv("/usr/bin/cc", args);
   return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

The above only compiles.  If you want to compile and run, you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
   system("cc -o ./a.out ./hellWorld.c");
   execl("./a.out", "a.out", NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

Although this is probably best done as a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

cc -o ./a.out ./hellWorld.c
./a.out
```

Comment: Okay, great. The error is no longer being thrown, but I think I may have explained the function of helloWorld.c incorrectly. helloWorld.c calls printf("hello world\n"); to print "hello world" to the terminal. After I made the changes you suggested, the file testExec.c compiles and runs with no errors, but "hello world" is not being displayed in the terminal.